# Issues deploying webApi to IIS 7 - ManagedPipelineHandler

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm stuck, looking for any help/suggestions with trying to get my webApi working on deployed test server. Works fine locally but can't get it working on published test site.  I'm publishing to an IIS 7 server, I've tried manual xcopy deploy as well as exporting my package from my local IIS and same issue.

I've enabled the Fault Trace on IIS and below is the particular module that it gives a warning on:

[MODULE SET RESPONSE ERROR STATUS]

ModuleName: ManagedPipelineHandler 
Notification: 128 
HttpStatus: 500 
HttpReason: Internal Server Error 
HttpSubStatus: 0 
ErrorCode: 0 
ConfigExceptionInfo: 
Notification: EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
ErrorCode: The operation completed successfully. (0x0)

The handler immediately preceeding this is [AspNetHttpHandler].

Comment: You should try plugging in the tracewriter to see if the Web API internals are throwing an exception http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0):

500 error is usually something wrong in your code. You can turn on error details on server temporarily:

```
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

And use fiddler to see what's wrong from response payload.